# Switch a branch and preserve current branch changes in Git

Tags: git, github

How do I switch the branch and still preserve my current branch changes?

Consider this scenario.

I am working on an issue and as per our development model, I create a separate branch and start working on it. I created my new branch using

> git checkout -b new_branch

Now it works fine when I do any changes in this branch.

But after this I forgot and switched back to default local branch(say "local"), due to system restart.

Now I started working on my fixes and suddenly realize that I am in "local" branch. Now because I have to commit my changes and merge it with master.

I am trying to do

> git checkout new_branch

But I keep getting this error which says :

> error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten
>   by checkout:
>           content/some/blah/blah/path_name/file.jsp
>
> Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch
>   branches. Aborting

How can I switch to the new_branch and still preserve my changes in local branch which I want to actually commit in new_branch.

PS :- stashing is not an option. Neither is git checkout on local branch. I want to preserve the changes.

Comment: Why is stashing not an option? It's the way to go in this case. (You might need to do manual conflict resolution when applying the stashed changes)

Comment: Actually there will be merge conflict when I will do "git stash pop". That is why I dont want to do git stash. Is there any way to resolve those conflicts? –

Comment: Yes, there will be. You changed the same lines or lines too close to each other. There's no way around it (Git can't figure out which change is the "real" change). Fix the conflicts manually.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: what kind of setup makes you change branch when the system restarts?

Answer (score 12):

Just stash the changes temporarily and immediately pop them right after switching branches.

```
git stash
git checkout new_branch
git stash pop
```

Comment: Actually there will be merge conflict when I will do "git stash pop". That is why I dont want to do git stash. Is there any way to resolve those conflicts?

Comment: In general you will not be able to avoid conflicts. After all, you wrote your changes with one view of the code and are trying to apply them to a different view. That diff simply won't apply cleanly if the files have changed between those two views.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisHayes, Just wanted to know if there is any better way to get these things resolved.

Comment: it would be better if you could add more information that what does `pop`ing stash mean?